# How to search numbers after decimal point for floating point number in Bash?

Tags: bash, floating-point

I am messing around with something on bash (I am very new to it).

I have a floating point number.

I want to to be able to check if there is any digits after the decimal point from 1-9 in order to determine whether it is a whole number - and do it within an if-else statement.

for example

```
if(*number does have a 1-9 digit after decimal*)
then
    echo 'Number is not a whole number'
else
    echo 'Number is a whole number'
fi
```

Dabbled with grep and REGEX but don't have a great grasp of it yet

Comment: You can use a `case` statement to match a pattern. If it matches `*.*` it has a decimal point.

Comment: You don't need `grep`, since `bash` has built-in glob and regexp matching.

Comment: The question needs to be clarified. `bash` does not have floating-point numbers. It works with strings. Numbers can be represented in strings in many ways. `3.1e3` uses a common format, an exponential notation, and it means 3.1 times 10 to the power of 3, which is 3100, so it is a whole number even though “3.1e3” has a non-zero digit after the decimal point. Do you want to work with only numerals that are guaranteed not to be in such an exponential notation?

Comment: E.g., is the numeral guaranteed to optionally start with “+” or “-”, have zero or more digit characters, then optionally a decimal point and then zero or more digit characters, but at least one digit character somewhere (excluding “.”, “+.” or “-.” as numerals; there must be at least one digit, as in “3.” or “.3”), and guaranteed not to have any other characters?

Answer (score -1):

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat findWhole.bash
#!/bin/bash
for x in 1.123456789 0001230045600.00 1.000000 1 1. 1.. 0002 .00 22.00023400056712300 1.00 .
do
  if [[ "$x" =~ ^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*[1-9][1-9]*[0-9]*$ ]]; then
    echo "$x is not a whole number"
  elif [[ "$x" =~ ^[0-9][0-9]*\.?0*$|^\.00*$ ]]; then
    echo "$x is a whole number"
  else
    echo "$x is not a number"
  fi
done
Mac_3.2.57$./findWhole.bash
1.123456789 is not a whole number
0001230045600.00 is a whole number
1.000000 is a whole number
1 is a whole number
1. is a whole number
1.. is not a number
0002 is a whole number
.00 is a whole number
22.00023400056712300 is not a whole number
1.00 is a whole number
. is not a number
Mac_3.2.57$
```